# libGDX Array Texture wrong

Tags: arrays, libgdx, textures

I have an error concerning libgdx textures. Can you help me fix my code? Thank you for watching my question:

```
topTube[0]=new Texture(String.format('alphabets_0');
topTube[1]=new Texture(String.format('alphabets_1');
...
topTube[10]=new Texture(String.format('alphabets_10');
```

To simple:

```
Texture[] topTube= new Texture[10];
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    topTube[i]=new Texture(String.format("alphabets_%d.png",i));
}
```

But I call `topTube[1]` or... When i did tested. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please include your error messages.

Comment: You're also missing a closing parenthesis in each of your first few statements.

Answer (score 1):

According to your given data, size of array should be 11(0 to 10).

```
Texture[] topTube= new Texture[11];
```

start your for loop from zero not from one.

```
for(int i=0;i<topTube.length;i++) {
    topTube[i]=new Texture(String.format("alphabets_%d.png",i));
}
```